# Cannot use Ctrl+Backspace/Del when renaming file on Windows

Tags: windows-10, text-editing

The question regards Windows OS and I don't know about other OS.

Since I learned that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> could delete whole words, I have been using extensively.

But it works "partially" in renaming file. When using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> it works correctly, while using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> enters some non-renerable character.

While I am alright with it (simple workaround by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>), I have question though:

1. Why it doesn't work in renaming files? Is there any reason to it?
2. Maybe this is some special case, when I have to use some other key combination?

Comment: Windows 10?????

Comment: @Moab yes, it's Windows 10

Comment: no idea why but [it works in Windows 11](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/p823z3/you_can_now_ctrl_backspace_when_renaming_a_file/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean Windows 10 install, Ctrl+Backspace not working anywhere](https://superuser.com/questions/1004761/clean-windows-10-install-ctrlbackspace-not-working-anywhere)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 Asks me to Enter a Password](https://superuser.com/questions/947281/windows-10-asks-me-to-enter-a-password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl+Backspace` is not a Windows keyboard shortcut, and as such is not implemented on an operating-system level. It is up to applications to implement the shortcut to delete whole words in text input. This means that some applications can exhibit different behavior. [Even NotePad only added support for the shortcut in 2018](https://www.howtogeek.com/353165/whats-new-in-windows-10s-redstone-5-update-available-fall-2018/).

Why Microsoft has not implemented the `Ctrl+Backspace` in File Explorer is anyone's guess. AFAIK there is no alternative shortcut for it.